# mock an abstract method with the same signature as another method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have 2 methods with almost the same signature. The only difference is that one of them uses the *specific type* and the other one uses the *base class*.

```
public abstract class CommandHandlerBase<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
        where TCommand : CommandBase
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public CommandHandlerBase(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public bool CanHandle(CommandBase command, Context context)
    {
        if (command.GetType() == typeof(TCommand))
            return CanHandle((TCommand)command, context);
        else
            return false;
    }

    public abstract bool CanHandle(TCommand command, Context context);

    public IEnumerable<EventBase> Handle(CommandBase command)
    {
        if (command.GetType() == typeof(TCommand))
            return Handle((TCommand)command);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("The handler cannot handle the given command type");
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<EventBase> Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Now I am trying to assert that the *specific* method is called if the *command type* is the correct type.

This is what I have so far:

```
var commandHandlerBaseMock = new Mock<CommandHandlerBase<TestCommand1>>(id);
commandHandlerBaseMock.CallBase = true;
var command = new TestCommand1();
commandHandlerBaseMock.Setup(ch => ch.CanHandle(command, null)).Returns(true);

bool result = commandHandlerBaseMock.Object.CanHandle(command, null);

result.Should().BeTrue();
```

The problem is that this asserts just that the called method is called, which is not helpful at all. The implementation is never hit.
Is there a way to mock just one specific overload of a method?

Comment: The test does nothing because the ```Act``` part here is just calling the method of the mock itself. Consider what is your system under test and provide instance of it in the test (instance not mock) and call the tested method. If the system under test has any dependencies then mock them. That is what mock is used for.

Comment: @dee I wanted to avoid implementing a derived class just for testing. But it seems I'll have to do that...

Comment: IMO there is nothing wrong to create testable class. Some people think it is bad practice but I found it useful many times.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code structure isn't sustainable... You're adding in instanceOf checks (usually a bad sign) and trying to shadow a signature polymorphically. Objects of type TCommand would always hit the TCommand specific implementation in your base class, I'd expect.

If you need two different handlers, based on two different types, consider not having a base class implementation at all *or* use the "Tell, Don't Ask" principle and push the handling into the command itself (you could possibly use the "Template Method" pattern in the abstract handler to do "generic stuff"), meaning you don't need any specialist code in your base class that's dependent on certain types.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Both interfaces have a different use. The non-generic one is used to access the objects via a common interface, the generic one is to be able to program against a strongly typed object (and not the base class). `CommandHandlerBase` just puts those 2 classes together so that the same checks dont have to be written for each implementation.